# How to apply pigeon hole principle to this question

Tags: combinatorics

I know the concept of the principle but I have no idea how to apply it to this question.

Show that among any $n+ 1$ positive integers, there must be two whose difference is a multiple of $n$.

Thanks

Comment: The pigeonholes are the numbers $0$ to $n-1$. For any pigeon (integer) $x$, the pigeonhole $x$ belongs to is the remainder when $x$ is divided by $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the residue classes mod $n$. How many are there?

What would it mean if there are two integers who have the same reside mod $n$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Think of all the positive integers $\mod n$. If two numbers are equal $\mod n$ then their difference is a multiple of $n$. Also, the only possible values of any integer are from $0 \mod n$ to $(n-1) \mod n$.